# Error loading child state with ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a working app though I am changing the architecture, cutting views down into smaller, more manageable documents. I currently have a state with a child state.

```
.state('patents', {
    url: '/patents',
    templateUrl: 'p3sweb/app/components/patents/views/list-patents.htm',
    controller: 'listPatentsCtrl',
    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
})
.state('patents.patent', {
    url: '/{patentId}/:patentHref',
    templateUrl: 'p3sweb/app/components/patents/views/patent-item.htm'
})
```

When I click on a table row in state `patents`, up pops `patents.patent` view below it.

I have now changed it so the child `patents.patent` state has multiple views like so:

```
.state('patents.patent', {
    url: '/{patentId}/:patentHref',
    templateUrl: 'p3sweb/app/components/patents/views/patent-item.htm',
       views: {
        '@': {
            templateUrl: 'p3sweb/app/components/patents/views/patent-item.htm'
        },
        'patentinfo@patents.patent': {
            templateUrl: 'p3sweb/app/components/patents/views/ui-views/patent-info.htm',
            controller: 'patentInfoCtrl',
            controllerAs: '$ctrl'                
        },
        'patentcostanalysis@patents.patent': {
            templateUrl: 'p3sweb/app/components/patents/views/ui-views/patent-costanalysis.htm',
            controller: 'patentCostAnalysisCtrl',
            controllerAs: '$ctrl'
        },
        'patentrenewals@patents.patent': {
            templateUrl: 'p3sweb/app/components/patents/views/ui-views/patent-renewals.htm',
            controller: 'patentRenewalsCtrl',
            controllerAs: '$ctrl'                
        }
    })
```

When I now click on the row in state `patents`, the `patents.patent` view replaces the parent view. So instead of displaying below it, it's the only view displayed.

***Question***

How do I resolve the issue that has occurred now I have included multiple views in `patents.patent` state?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out, after reading [ui-router wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views), using @ creates an absolute path, and I wasn't targeting the view in the parent state `patents`.

So instead of

```
views: {
    '@': {
        templateUrl: 'p3sweb/app/components/patents/views/patent-item.htm'
     }
```

It should of been

```
views: {
    '@patents': {
        templateUrl: 'p3sweb/app/components/patents/views/patent-item.htm'
     }
```